# Ruby version is not upgrading on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have upgraded my application from ruby 1.9.2 to ruby 1.9.3 on heroku.

I followed the article on heroku about it:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

When I deployed my application, I didn't get any error:

```
> -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.rc.2 Running: bundle install --without development:test --path
> vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment Fetching gem metadata from
> http://rubygems.org/....... Fetching gem metadata from
> http://rubygems.org/.. Using rake (0.9.2.2) Using i18n (0.6.0)
> ..............
> -----> Discovering process types Procfile declares types -> worker Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web
> -----> Compiled slug size is 27.0MB
> -----> Launching... done, v157 http://riskyshower.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

But the application can't be launched properly, if I tail the logs, I see the following:

```
2012-08-16T10:21:26+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET my_domain.me/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-16T10:21:27+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET my_domain.me/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I can't get any more info to tell me what is wrong, but I guess Ruby hasn't been upgraded properly, because when I do :

```
heroku run "ruby -v"
Running ruby -v attached to terminal... up, run.1
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

When it's supposed to be 1.9.3

At the top of my Gemfile I have:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
```

I'm using the latest version of bundler:

```
bundle -v
Bundler version 1.2.0.rc.2
```

And I have the correct path to ruby I guess (like in the article):

```
heroku config -s | grep PATH
PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:bin
```

Any idea on what I should run to force the upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't read the documentation with enough attention.

My heroku PATH was

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

The documentation says:

> If absent or not the first entry, add bin: to the config with heroku
>   config:add. $ heroku config:add
>   PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Not the **first entry** term (not simply *present* as I thought), obviously I needed to add the 'bin' in front of the PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're on the Cedar stack? I believe that's the only way you can set the Ruby version that way on Heroku. If not, switching to the Cedar stack might solve your problem.

Comment: I had a bin/ path missing in my ruby PATH, see my answer :) thanks for your help!