# Why Heroku is still not using my Ruby version 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed every step in here:
I have this in my gem file

```
ruby "1.9.3"
```

and then when I deploy heroku says:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
```

Then when I do

```
heroku run "ruby -v"
```

I still get

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

Then I added a path:

```
heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Deployed again, and still same result:

I tried:

```
heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Still no use:

In my heroku Log I get this:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:390:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.2, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

It kind of is driving me nuts, I can't get Heroku to use 1.9.3.

I looked at the following questions as well:
[Ruby version is not upgrading on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991689/ruby-version-is-not-upgrading-on-heroku)
[Is it possible to run my Rails app on Heroku with Ruby 1.9.3? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784421/is-it-possible-to-run-my-rails-app-on-heroku-with-ruby-1-9-3-if-so-how)
[How can I choose Ruby version on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613948/how-can-i-choose-ruby-version-on-heroku)
[Heroku cedar doesn't upgrade to ruby-1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659576/heroku-cedar-doesnt-upgrade-to-ruby-1-9-3?rq=1)

Still can't get anywhere

Comment: @Casper I might have confused you sorry, but actually I want my app to use ruby "1.9.3". So, yes I do have ruby "1.9.3" in my Gemfile, which means Heroku might pick that up.
However I still tried to choose the version through those steps.

Comment: Your application may be using Ruby 1.9.3.  All you know here is `heroku run "ruby -v"` doesn't use it.

Comment: @NickVeys What about the error in my Heroku log :/ ? and I can't run any Heroku command it keeps saying `Ruby version is 1.9.2, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3`

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice that.  Sorry!  Not sure what's going on there.  Heroku support is usually pretty fast, that's probably your best route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very painful search by removing and adding stuff from my most recent commit I realized that a file .`bash_profile` was added to my Rails Root app that had this in it:

```
export PGHOST=localhost
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

So I just removed that, because this calls up the path to the Ruby version, the default one.
I hope no one ends up making same mistake.